# Run application without UAC from application with UAC enabled

Tags: windows-vista, uac

My current process of 'explorer.exe' is UAC enabled (has elevated permissions), but any program I start using the Start Menu etc. also has UAC enabled now.

How can I disable this? So, how can I run an application without elevated permissions from an application *with* elevated permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running as a normal user, for example `runas` allows you to do this.

And I don't see a point in having `explorer.exe` run elevated? Can you explan why you did that?

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry for the delay in response. I ran task manager using elevated permissions so as to display all processes. Then, explorer.exe crashed and I ran it again out of the (elevated) task manager...

Comment: @pmvdb: Well, you can choose whether you want to elevate or not: http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/1c8134aa-b563-4f51-ad57-b7017fb1fb83/2011-02-19_2327.png

Comment: I must be using another version of Windows I guess... http://i.imgur.com/hfM8N.png

Comment: @pimvdb: Oh, Vista, no clue then...